# In Google Sheets, how to join 3 cells, in 3 different ways, depending on the contents of 1 of those cells

Tags: google-sheets

I started this on 1/26 and learned I had curly quotes that were breaking the formula. I worked through that, with help here, but now I'm at the last piece, allowing 2 owners with different last names to print out like I want them to.

So far my formula works “OK”, but it’s not perfect:
=TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE,(IMPORTRANGE("","Directory!D5")),IF((IMPORTRANGE("","Directory!E5"))<>"","&",""),(IMPORTRANGE("","Directory!E5")),(IMPORTRANGE("","Directory!C5")))

What exists on Worksheet A:
Column C               Column D              Column E
LAST NAME (1st OWNER)  1st NAME (1st OWNER)  2nd OWNER {1st, (LAST)}
Ex 1  Smith Marshall         Julie                 ---
Ex 2  Jones                  Chris                 Samantha
Ex 3  Anderson               Patrick               Jane Doe

How I want it to pull onto Worksheet B:
Column C
OWNER(S)                     WHAT “SHOULD” PRINT IN THE CELL
Ex 1  Julie Smith Marshall         NO “&” symbol
Ex 2  Chris & Samantha Jones       “&” symbol between the 2 first names
Ex 3  Patrick Anderson & Jane Doe  “&” symbol between the 2 full names

BUT, what I’m getting on Worksheet B, using the code above:
Column C
OWNER(S)                      WHAT ”IS” PRINTING IN THE CELL
Ex 1  Julie Smith Marshall          NO “&” symbol
Ex 2  Chris & Samantha Jones        “&” symbol between the 2 first names
Ex 3  Patrick & Jane Doe Anderson   2nd owner name in the middle of
1st owner F/L name

[image: Cell-Contents]

What I think I need…somehow:

1. currently…
   A. if there is NO value in Column E, this is working fine (ex. 1)
   B. if there IS a value in Column E, and it’s ONLY ONE WORD (a “first” name), this is working fine (ex. 2)
   C. BUT, this is NOT working if the Column E value is TWO WORDS (a “first” and a “last” name)
   D. NOTE: Column E is entered in the cell as: FirstName LastName (ex. 3)
2. so to brainstorm…
   A. NOTE: data on Worksheet A is VERY “clean”; NO extraneous “spaces”, etc.; I did the “trim whitespace” action, and there was none
   B. right now the IMPORTRANGE “read” is in this order:  Column D, if Column E is blank skip Column E else print the "&" then Column E then Column C
   C. the only difference between when it works/not is the # words/names in Column E
   D. so if Column E is NOT blank, then it needs to check for a “space” in that text...
   i. if there is NO space, do what it’s doing now,
   a. print the "&" then Column E
   b. so the print order is:  D “&” E C
   ii. if there IS a space, then skip and
   a. go to next IMPORTRANGE for Column C
   b. then print the "&" then do IMPORTRANGE for Column E then print Column E
   c. so the print order ends up:  D C “&” E
   E. I’ve ruled out, for various reasons:
   i. QUERY
   ii. LIST
   iii. FILTER
   iv. ARRAYFORMULA
   v. CONCATENATE
   F. I keep thinking I should be able to “nest” these functions within the IF function
   G. I have played with TEXTJOIN and the IF function in conjunction with:
   i. SEARCH
   ii. MATCH
   iii. REGEXMATCH

But alas, I’ve struck out on every attempt…ARGH! I’m not having any luck with getting a successful function that “works”! I just keep getting “formula parse error”. I’ve verified all of my quotation marks are straight quotes. I’ve verified equivalent open/close parentheses. I’ve verified my . I’m just frustrated and lost. Can anyone point me in the correct direction? Much appreciation for ANY help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the `'Directory'` sheet, insert this formula in row 2 of a free column:

```
=arrayformula( 
  ifs( 
    isblank(E2:E), 
      D2:D & " " & C2:C, 
    regexmatch(E2:E, " "), 
      D2:D & " " & C2:C & " & " & E2:E, 
    len(E2:E), 
      D2:D & " & " & E2:E & " " & C2:C, 
    true, 
      C2:C 
  ) 
)
```

You can then copy the results from the new column to the target tab with an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), or to another spreadsheet file with `importrange()`.